# How to call a function from another function, with ng-click?

Tags: angularjs

```
 var vm = this;
            vm.dt_data = [];               
            vm.item = {};
            vm.edit = edit;
            vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                .withOption('initComplete', function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        $compile($('.dt-uikit .md-input'))($scope);
                    })
                })
                .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
                .withOption('createdRow', function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                    $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
                })
                .withOption('ajax', {
                    dataSrc: function(json) {
                        json['draw']=1
                        json['recordsFiltered'] = json.records.length                            
                        json['recordsTotal'] =json.records.length
                        console.log(json)
                        return json.records;
                      },
                    url: 'http://localhost:808/sistemadrp/public/ws/usuarios',
                    type: 'GET',
                })
                //.withDataProp('records')
                .withOption('processing', true)
                .withOption('serverSide', true);

            vm.dtColumns = [
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('Id'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('usuario').withTitle('Usuario'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('nombre').withTitle('Nombre'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('email').withTitle('Email'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('telefono').withTitle('Telefono'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('estado').withTitle('Estado'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('created_at').withTitle('Creado'),
              DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Acciones').notSortable().renderWith(function(data,type,full){
                  vm.item[data.id] = data; 
                    return  ' <a href="#" data-uk-modal="{target:\'#modal_header_footer\'}" ng-click="showCase.edit(showCase.item[' + data.id + '])">'+
                            ' <i class="md-icon material-icons md-bg-light-blue-900 uk-text-contrast"></i></a>'+
                            ' <a href="#" data-uk-modal="{target:\'#modal_header_footer_eliminar\'}" ng-click="showCase.edit(showCase.item[' + data.id + '])">'+
                            ' <i class="md-icon material-icons md-bg-red-900 uk-text-contrast">&#xE872;</i></a>';
              })                    
          ];
```

Table:

```
 <div class="md-card-content" ng-controller="dt_default as showCase">
            <table datatable="" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions"  dt-columns="showCase.dtColumns" class="uk-table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            </table></div>
```

With the answer I was given here to make use of $ compile already works this way

```
.withOption('createdRow', function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
            })
```

Now when clicking the button I even call a modal and I command the object to make use of the ng-model

Thanks for the help, it works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: Added snippet for demonstrating the usage of *[$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)*

- In the html there is only a `body` tag for initialising the app and a div for initialising the controller.
- In `foo` controller, two link are created as simple strings but with two `ng-click` respectively and then compiled with the $compile service. The result of that is then appended to the `div` which `id` is `parent` created as jQlite object (important aspect here!), so when the links are clicked the functions on their `ng-click` are executed (see console). It means AngularJS as interpreted properly the compiled html.

*IMPORTANT*: The difference between this and your code may be that your `renderWith` just take the parameter as a simple html node and not a *jQuery*/*jQlite* object. If that's the case **you can not** do what you're trying to do this way. You probably will need to find a workaround for this. For example: you could set a selector (i.e.: an `id`) for the result of the object returned by the `DTColumnBuilder` and then *$compile* that html node the same way I show in the snippet.

**Original post**

You should use the [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service. Modify your function like this:

```
function actionsHtml(data, type, full, meta){
        vm.usuario[data.id] = data; 
        var html = ' <a href="#" data-uk-modal="{target:\'#modal_header_footer\'}" ng-click="showCase.edit(showCase.usuario[' + data.id + '])"><i class="md-icon material-icons md-bg-light-blue-900 uk-text-contrast"></i></a>'+
               ' <a href="#" data-uk-modal="{target:\'#modal_header_footer_eliminar\'}"><i class="md-icon material-icons md-bg-red-900 uk-text-contrast">&#xE872;</i></a>';

  return $compile(angular.element(html))($scope);
}
```

*Snippet*

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('foo', function($scope, $compile) {

    var html = "<a class='hand' ng-click='hello()'><strong>Hi</strong> <small>(Click Me and take a look at console)</small></a>" +
      "<br/> <hr/>" +
      "<a class='hand' ng-click='goodby()'><strong>Goodby</strong> <small>(Click Me and take a look at console)</small></a>";
    /*
     * important!! if you don't use the angular.element syntaxt below, and instead you just use
     * 'document.getElementById('parent') = $compile(html)($scope)', for instance, it will be shown something like '[object], [object]'
     */
    angular.element(document.getElementById('parent')).append($compile(html)($scope));

    $scope.hello = function() {
      console.log("Hi there!")
    }

    $scope.goodby = function() {
      console.log("Goodby!")
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
  .hand {
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>

<body ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="foo">

    <div id="parent"></div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It returns an array with two objects

Comment: Those objects are _jQlite objects_ and the objects are the two links. Aren't they? The first one is the one with the `showCase.edit` call, isn't it? Well, this one should execute that func on click. The difference is that this one should **do** the call properly since the content was compiled by AngularJS

Comment: In the view shows [Object object], which I understand are the 2 buttons, but it does not return them as buttons but as well as text. They should be buttons.

Comment: OK, let me check that. I'll give you some feedback later

Comment: @JG_GJ, I made an edit to my answer. I think the key point with your code is what accepts the `renderWith` function of your `DTColumnBuilder` the _$compile_ service return a jQlite/jQuery object, that's why you saw the `[object] [object]` expression

Comment: If it works for me when I add the div with id = "parent", but the buttons show inside div, and I want them to appear in the table. How to do that, thank you very much.

Comment: Tried DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withClass('parent').withTitle('Acciones').notSortable().renderWith(actionsHtml). But it shows me all the buttons for each record

Comment: @JG_GJ, use a `span` instead , not a `div`.

Comment: Already thank you very much was to add the following to the datatable..withOption('createdRow', function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                        $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
                    })

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a scope issue to me. 
This means at run time, when the button is clicked, it cannot find the edit function.

If you add this line below vm.usario = {};

```
vm.edit = edit;
```

Then change your ng-click="showCase.edit( to be

```
ng-click="vm.edit( ...
```

Then the button should be able to find the function.