# Angular 1.x trying to add ng-click to dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My trying to create dynamically an element and during the creation attach an `ng-click` to it. I know I need to `compile` that element, only it isn't working. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759497/angularjs-dynamically-set-attribute) but not able to make it work with my element.

```
function compile(element){
    var el = angular.element(element);    
    $scope = el.scope();
      $injector = el.injector();
      $injector.invoke(function($compile){
         $compile(el)($scope)
      })     
  }

function foo(){
    var element = angular.element("<"+element+" ng-click='x()' placeholder='input'>");
    compile(element);
}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42539999/how-to-call-a-function-from-another-function-with-ng-click/42540297#42540297) out

Comment: Is this in a directive?

Comment: No, in a function.. I didnt separate the code properly here. Please see edit.

Comment: function where though? if in directive or controller have access directly to scope

Comment: @lealceldeiro comment was very helpful. Thank you all.