# ng-click not responding when HTML added by JavaScript

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

ng-click is not working as it should. I tried looking at documentation and tutorials but couldn't find the reason.

I have a JavaScript variable storing html template. which by using

```
document.getElementById('someId').innerHTML = emptypage;
```

where emptypage is a JavaScript variable, is implemented inside a div with id=someId.

My Code:

```
var emptypage=` <md-toolbar `+ this.createID() +` class="md-accent 
 soopsObject" ng-app="vdApp">
        <span class="example-spacer ng-controller="vdNav">
            <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left" md-component-id="left" md- 
             disable-backdrop md-whiteframe="4">
                <md-content layout-margin>
                    <p>
                        About
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Contact
                    </p>
                    <md-button ng-click="toggleLeft()" class="md-accent">
                        Close
                    </md-button>
                </md-content>
            </md-sidenav>
            <div>
                <md-button ng-click="toggleLeft()">
                    <md-icon>menu</md-icon> Menu
                </md-button>
            </div>
    </span>         
    </md-toolbar>`;
```

My Controller:

```
    var nav=angular.module("vdApp", []);
    nav.controller("vdNav", function($scope, $mdSidenav) {
    alert("inside leftToggle");

    $scope.toggleLeft = buildToggler('left');

    function buildToggler(componentId){
        return function(){
            $mdSidenav(componentId).toggle();
        };
    }
});
```

Even alert isn't working.
What am I doing wrong? Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Is there an ng-controller somewhere telling AngularJS that the HTML code you posted is supposed to be handled by the vdNav controller? Or something else having the same effect (a route definition)?

Comment: Yes it is. Actually ng-app and ng-controller are there in the parent element of the div element.

Comment: Post a **complete**, minimal example reproducing the problem. Look for errors in your console. If there is one, fix it.

Comment: no errors in console.

Comment: I've added the relevant html part in the question. @JBNizet

Comment: So your HTML isn't actually an HTML template or page, but a JavaScript variable? Again, post a complete minimal example reproducing the error.

Comment: will this suffice? or do I need to elaborate a bit more. @JBNizet

Comment: ng-app can only work if it's in the page when angular.js is executed. You're adding it dynamically (for a reason I can't understand), so that can't work. Read the documentation of ng-app.

Comment: When HTML with AngularJS directives is added to the DOM, those directives need to be compiled and linked to the AngularJS framework. DOM manipulation should only be done by the AngularJS framework, not by JavaScript.

Comment: @SouravKumar, [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42539999/how-to-call-a-function-from-another-function-with-ng-click/42540297#42540297) might help you.